# Spring security : sec:authorize tag gives stream closed exception

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using **Spring security 3.0.6**. The following JSP snippet is the culprit :

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR')">
                         <a href="<s:url value='/exitUser' />">
                            Switch back to your own role</a>
</sec:authorize>
```

The following exception is thrown :

```
    Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
# Messages:     Stream closed
File:   org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspWriterImpl.java
Line number:    210
Stacktraces
java.io.IOException: Stream closed

    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:210)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:915)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:652)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:123)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

I have successfully switched the user to another role and is now trying to display the link to switch back to his own role, but only if he has actually switched. I gather that the user has **ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR** if he has switched roles, and so I am doing the above.

I have included the **tag library** via :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Comment: There must be another underlying error that you are not seeing. Review the tomcat logs to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not specified

```
<http use-expressions="true">
```

in my spring security xml. After having done that, and changing the **intercept urls** to use expressions in their **accepts** values, the error disappeared. Wasn't able to reproduce the error in a simple test application though.

**Edit** : Another instance where I found this error was when I was using a custom **SPEL** expression in the `authorize` tag, and there was a `NullPointerException` in the method which handled the expression.

Basically, it seems that the this error usually hides an underlying error in evaluating the expression used in the `authorize` (or any) tag